# How to get maximum and minimum of a list in column?

Tags: python, pandas, list

Given that, I have a dataframe as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict = {
        "A": [[1,2,3,4],[3],[2,8,4],[5,8]]
}

dt = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

I wish to have the Maximum *and* minimum of each row in column B. My favorite output is:

```
              A    B
0  [1, 2, 3, 4]    [1,4]
1           [3]    [3,3] 
2     [2, 8, 4]    [2,8] 
3        [5, 8]    [5,8]
```

What I already tried is the below code which does not work:

```
dt["B"] =[np.min(dt.A), np.max(dt.A)]
```

Comment: i meant, something like a loop in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas however, `apply` is a good solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like this:

```
In [1592]: dt['B'] = dt.A.apply(lambda x: [min(x), max(x)])     
In [1593]: dt                                   
Out[1593]: 
              A       B
0  [1, 2, 3, 4]  [1, 4]
1           [3]  [3, 3]
2     [2, 8, 4]  [2, 8]
3        [5, 8]  [5, 8]
```

As suggested by @Ch3steR, using `map` since it's faster:

```
dt['B'] = dt.A.map(lambda x: [min(x), max(x)])
```

Comment: `dt.A.map(...)` is a little faster than `pd.Series.apply` as `pd.Series.map` is made for element-wise calculations. And `map` was around ~20-30µs faster not much though.

Answer (score 10):

You can create `DataFrame`, then minimal and maximal values by [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html), convert to lists and assign back if requirement is no loops (`Apply` are loops under the hood):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dt.A.tolist())
dt['B'] = df.agg(['min','max'], axis=1).astype(int).values.tolist()
print (dt)
              A       B
0  [1, 2, 3, 4]  [1, 4]
1           [3]  [3, 3]
2     [2, 8, 4]  [2, 8]
3        [5, 8]  [5, 8]
```

If no problem with loops another solution with `list comprehension`, it should be faster like `apply`, depends of real data:

```
dt['B'] =  [[min(x), max(x)] for x in dt.A]
```

Comment: Out of all the solutions `[[min(x), max(x)] for x in dt.A]` was the fastest. +1

Comment: @Ch3steR was it faster than the first solution of jez? I wouldnt expect it.

Comment: @Erfan Yes, I `timeit` all the solutions. And *list comp* was the fastest by 10x than the second fastest solution. May be my analysis may not be fair cause I didnot test it with large lists and large DataFrame.

Comment: Ah oke, I think comparison should be done on reasonably large data to see the efficiency of the methods.

Comment: @Erfan With large data I would use some custom function which would calculate `min` and `max` in a single pass may be using `cython`. Here we are iterating twice over the same iterable when it can be done in one pass and if lists are small it wouldn't matter anyway. Testing with large data is better I agree.

Comment: In the first method its not. Its all vectorized methods. Thats why I dont expect it to be slower than the loop. Actually im pretty sure it would be quite faster.

Comment: @Erfan - I modify answer, because I think it depends of data.

Answer (score 6):

Just an alternative with [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html):

```
dt['B'] = (dt['A'].explode().astype(int).groupby(level=0).agg(['min','max'])
           .to_numpy().tolist())
print(dt)
```

---

```
              A       B
0  [1, 2, 3, 4]  [1, 4]
1           [3]  [3, 3]
2     [2, 8, 4]  [2, 8]
3        [5, 8]  [5, 8]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use list comprehension on sorted values in dt.A

```
 dt['B']= [[row[0], row[-1]] for row in dt.A.map(lambda x: sorted(x))]
```

[image]